# Adding content to

Tags: android, android-layout

I have watched many tutorials on Android app development and have followed alot of the guidelines provided by Google here: https://developer.android.com/index.html However, I can't find any details of where I can add content when using the "Navigation Drawer Activity"

This activity is part of the SDK and I want to know how I can add content to the items which are selected using the Navigation Drawer. I can work out how to change the string names etc, just can't work out how to actually get content onto the pages.

Comment: have a look http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you add this as an answer please so I can accept it?